# Lazy loading and Isotope - working in Firefox, but not IE

Tags: css, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

I have had a go at implementing lazy loader on my site. See the sandbox here:

http://www.brencecoghill.com/projects/north-vietnam/

the following text was added to my isotope to make this work (along wit the necessary html and linking to the library from the header):

```
$("img").lazyload({
    event : 'scroll',
    effect : 'fadeIn',
    appear: function(){
    }
});
```

This appears to work fine in firefox, but is a total fail in IE (i tested with version 8) - just displaying grey boxes.

1. how do I fix this to work in IE? (at least version 8 or greater)
2. is there a way to setup lazyloader so that it degrades nicely?

FYI I used these links to figure out how to implement this:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

[Combining jQuery Isotope and Lazy Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337291/combining-jquery-isotope-and-lazy-load)

http://jsbin.com/ajoded

http://jsfiddle.net/wN6tC/73/

**EDIT: i remove the line that was trying to write to the console above. Any other suggestions on fixing the other script errors I am getting?**

Comment: Just tried that link in IE7 and the first issue I found is that you have something being written to `console`. There is no such thing in IE so that will always break. Remove the `console` statements and see if it works. Besides that your design is broken in other places in IE7.

Comment: i removed the line writing to the console. thanks. Any suggestions on what is causing the other errors?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in IE now that you removed `console` but you still have a js error. I am not certain why that error is occuring, maybe it's the `jQuery.noConflict();`

IE:

```
SCRIPT5002: Function expected 
animate-bg.js, line 8 character 1
```

Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function animate-bg.js:71 (anonymous function)
animate-bg.js:71
```

To answer the second question..

> > is there a way to setup lazyloader so that it degrades nicely?

You could follow the instructions "[Fallback for Non JavaScript Browsers](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)". Which is basically to setup code for images like this:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">
<noscript><img src="img/example.jpg" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>
```

Then add some CSS to hide

```
 .lazy { display: none; }
```

When the page's jquery loads immediately call something like this to show the images again.

```
$("img.lazy").show().lazyload();
```